# SSHLibrary UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa9 in position 660: invalid start byte

Tags: python, ssh, robotframework

I am using Robot Framework SSHLibrary to open connection with a RHEL server. But connection was unsuccessful. Robot Framework throws the following error

```
FAIL : UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa9 in position 660: invalid start byte
20151212 12:47:36.022 : DEBUG : 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\SSHLibrary\library.py", line 792, in login
    return self._login(self.current.login, username, password, delay)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\SSHLibrary\library.py", line 832, in _login
    login_output = login_method(username, *args)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\SSHLibrary\abstractclient.py", line 150, in login
    return self._read_login_output(delay)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\SSHLibrary\abstractclient.py", line 165, in _read_login_output
    return self.read(delay)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\SSHLibrary\abstractclient.py", line 299, in read
    return self._decode(output)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\SSHLibrary\abstractclient.py", line 302, in _decode
    return output.decode(self.config.encoding)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
```

Comment: `'\0xa9'.decode('utf-8')`  `'\0xa9'.encode('latin-1')` ...can you please put the line of string that cause the problem

Comment: No, during SSH connection my remote machine was giving response to Robot Framework, I cant modify those. By default Robot Framework encoding is UTF-8 so its unable to recognise HEX characters.

Answer (score 0):

In **Open Connection** Robot Framework keyword gave **encoding=latin-1** as Latin character representation was present in my login response from remote server.
Login successful.